# AWS: Trying to connect to S3 Bucket, Getting CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, cors, storage

I'm getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/public/requests/fbb63ea5-6d89-4d5b-88f8-161e4355cedc/67c7f705-1a68-4a90-a3d7-2f943ddaf47f.png?x-id=PutObject' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

when I try adding a file to the storage bucket. Anyone get this before?

Comment: You might need to add a CORS policy to the bucket. See: [Using cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html)